# Local existence of parallel vector field

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $M$ be a Riemannian manifold, $p\in M$ be a point in the manifold, and $\xi\in T_p M$ be a vector in its tangent space.  I am wondering whether, for some small neighborhood $U\subset M$, it is possible to define a vector field $V$ such that $V(p) = \xi$ and such that $V$ is parallel.  That is, the covariant derivative $\nabla V$ vanishes, $\nabla V = 0$.

The intuitive way to try to construct this is to take normal coordinates at $p$, and defining $V$ by parallel transporting it along the radial direction.  I just don't know how to prove that the resulting vector field is parallel.

Suppose this procedure works to construct a parallel vector field locally.  And suppose that the normal coordinates at $p$ can be extended to all of $M$ diffeomorphically (which may happen if $M$ has nonpositive curvature).  Can $V$ be extended to all of $M$?

Any help with these questions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

@John Ma's answer is a good one, but I'd also like to point out that parallel vector fields are even rarer that Killing vector fields.  For example, on a round sphere, there are plenty of Killing vector fields but no nontrivial parallel fields. Basically, the existence of a parallel vector field is equivalent to the condition that the metric splits locally into a Riemannian product of a one-dimensional manifold and an $(n-1)$-dimensional one. This implies, in particular, that the sectional curvatures of planes containing $V$ are all zero.

Comment: Yes, I was about to add that, for example, for a surface with a parallel unit vector field $e_1$ on $U$, taking the orthonormal frame $e_1,e_2$, since $\nabla e_1=0$, it follows that the connection form $\omega_{12}=0$ on $U$, and so, in particular, the Gaussian curvature on $U$ is $0$. This generalizes immediately to $n$ dimensions to prove @JackLee's assertion.

Comment: Do you have a reference or an easy proof of the statement regarding the local splitting of the metric? (Also, Is there such a theorem in the more general context of connections on vector bundles? That is, suppose that a vector bundle admits a non-zero parallel section. Does the connection splits locally as a direct sum of connections? Thanks).

Comment: @Jack Lee To reiterate Asaf Schachar's question, do you have a reference for the local splitting assertion?

Comment: @AmorFati: See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3389908/1421).

Answer (score 9):

This is too strong a condition. $\nabla V = 0$ would imply that $V$ is a Killing vector field, thus the local one parameter subgroup of diffeomorphisms are isometries. As isometry preserves curvature, one can construct examples so that such a local vector field can't be found. For example, one can take a surface so that it's Gauss curvature attains a strict maximum/minimum at $p$.